# How to send and receive multipart binary SMS?

Tags: android, arrays, smsmanager

I have a big data/binary  to send via SMS using SmsManager, i'm using `sendDataMessage`

, but there is no methode to send a big data like in the txt msg `sendMultipartTextMessage`, any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

Binary SMS Sender:-

> Requires android.permission.SEND_SMS permission (see above).

```
String strPhone = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
String strMessage = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890TEST";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

ArrayList<String> messageParts = sms.divideMessage(strMessage);

sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(strPhone, null, messageParts, null, null);

Toast.makeText(this, "Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If you want more detail about above thing than you have to visit [this](http://codetheory.in/android-sms/) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1044639/android-sms-mms-api-sending-sms-mms-receiving-sms).

Comment: thanks for reply @duggu ,this is works for me, but it is a simple SMS , i want to send a multipart binary SMS,